# Has anyone had any success integrating CiviCRM into Craft CMS?

Tags: cms-integration

We have a potential client whose site is currently using CiviCRM and Drupal. They are interested in using Craft CMS. I've researched other CRM plugins for Craft similar to CiviCRM but they do not exist. We would like to stay with CiviCRM but has anyone had any success integrating the two?

Thanks
S.

Answer (score 3):

I would strongly expect the answer to be No simply because integrating with a CMS is a big task and the only 3 that are officially done are WP Joomla and Drupal as I am sure you are aware. There are however solutions for having CiviCRM separate from a CMS but still have forms etc available eg

[Remote Forms](https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.remoteform)

[CiviCRM Modular Remote-Access Framework](https://github.com/CiviMRF/documentation)

Comment: Don't forget Backdrop CMS too!

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends on what's meant by "integration".  CiviCRM can install as a plugin to Drupal/Backdrop/Joomla/WordPress, which gives certain integration points, but that's not the only way to integrate CiviCRM.

As Pete points out, there's Remote Forms and CiviMRF for integrating with any site.  There's also [Form Processor](https://civicrm.org/blog/jaapjansma/using-civicrm-form-processor-extension-to-handle-form-submissions-from-an-external) and [Data Processor](https://civicrm.org/extensions/data-processor) if you have complex needs.  E.g.:

- I intend to use Form Processor to allow a remote site to open new cases in CiviCRM for a client.
- For another client, I intend to use Data Processor to display a membership directory and map based on real-time Civi data on a remote site.  That site is WordPress, so I'm using [Content Views CiviCRM](https://civicrm.org/blog/justinfreeman/show-civicrm-content-quickly-easily-in-wordpress-using-content-views) and [Leaflet Map](https://wordpress.org/plugins/leaflet-map/) plugins to simplify things on the remote site - but Craft has its own JSON viewers.

Answer (score 1):

Anything is possible if you've got the time and resources but if you are looking for a dependable and cost effective solution to use CiviCRM on a website, you are going to have to use Drupal, Wordpress or Joomla.

I would find out why the client wants to use Craft as opposed to Drupal. More likely than not it's because their Drupal site is poorly configured and they aren't getting the most out of it. My plan would be to do a deep dive with the client to assess their use of the site, how the site is configured and come up with a plan to make it work for them.

You could put CiviCRM on a headless Drupal instance and build an API endpoint to communicate with the Craft site but that seems like an awful lot of work for very little return.